# Thymeleaf #sets.contains() always returning false despite usage according to documentation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**Preface**

I have a spring boot application with a `User` entity with a set of `Role`.

On the edit user template, I am displaying the user's roles with a `<select>`multiple. When rending the view of a existing `User` with its set of `Role`, I am trying to only mark as selected the roles within the set.

Thymeleaf provides two tools for this:

`th:selected`: Which expects a boolean value (true being selected)

`#sets`: Which provides a handful of useful methods similar to `java.util.Set`, the one being used in this case is `contains()`.

**The problem**

When adding to the model a found `User` and all the possibles `Role` in the form of a HashSet, using `#sets.contains()` always return false when using the found user's roles and all the roles as parameters, therefore not selecting the user's roles when loading the form.

If I use the notation `th:selected="${{user.roles}}"` notation all the options are selected (even those the user does not posses).

**The Code**

*User*

```
public class User
{

    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String passwordConfirm;
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getPasswordConfirm()
    {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm)
    {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    public Set<Role> getRoles()
    {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles)
    {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

*Role*

```
public class Role
{

private Long id;
private String name;
private Set<User> users;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
public Set<User> getUsers()
{
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users)
{
    this.users = users;
}
}
```

*Controller*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController
{
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

    @RequestMapping("/user/edit/{id}")
    public String editUser(Model model, @PathVariable("id") long id)
    {
        User user = userService.findByUserId(id);
        HashSet<Role> foundRoles = roleService.getAllRoles();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("userRoles", foundRoles);
        return "admin/adminUserDetail";
    }

}
```

*The form*

```html
<form role="form" th:action="@{/registration}" method="POST"
              th:object="${user}">
            <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <h3 class="alert-heading">It seems we have a couple problems with your input</h3>
                    <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}"></li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username: </label> <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="${user.username}"
                                                 placeholder="Username" name="username"/>

                <label>Password: </label> <input class="form-control" type="password" th:field="${user.password}"
                                                 placeholder="Password" name="password"/>

                <label>Password Confirm: </label> <input type="password"
                                                         th:field="${user.passwordConfirm}" class="form-control"
                                                         placeholder="Password Confirm"/>

                <select class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                    <option th:each="role : ${userRoles}"
                            th:value="${role.id}"
                            th:selected="${#sets.contains(user.roles, role)}"
                            th:text="${role.name}">Role name
                    </option>
                </select>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Your `User` nor your `Role` has a `hashCode` implementation. so each new `Role` will have a different hashcode. Depending on the type of set the hashcode or equals is used to determine if the object is in there. You have neither so it will always return false.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'm using a `HashSet` for my `Set` implementation, therefore it is doing an object comparison when invoking contains(), which requires an explicit method of comparing the objects involved. This comparison uses both `equals` and `hashcode` methods of the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `Set` the object in there must implement both `hashCode` and `equals` as that is used to determine if an object is already in the `Set`. Unless it is a `SortedSet` which uses either a `Comparator` or the natural order expressed through your object implementing `Comparable`.

As you don't do either of those using `contains` will simply always return `false` even for a seemingly same `Role` instance. Because according to the contract they aren't.

To fix implement the `equals` and `hashCode` method in your `User` and `Role` object.

```
public class Role {

    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.name);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) { return true; }
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Role) ) { return false; }
        return Objects.equals(this.name, ((Role) o).name);
    }

}
```

Something along those lines should do the trick.